# Import .n43 file to Quicken?

Tags: quicken, spain, ofx

One of my banks is Spanish, and allows downloading activity in the `.n43` format (aka "Norma 43") which is some kind of Spanish version of OFX/QFX.

Any way (on a Mac) that I can convert this to an OFX file?

The only tool I found was https://pythonhosted.org/csb43/ but it throws a bunch of errors on run, such as:

```
Validation failed for reference '000958145698'
Bad format: content 'A82018474000' mismatches the expected format r'^\d{12}$' for this field
Validation failed for reference '000960545562'
Bad format: content 'PayPal Europe S.' mismatches the expected format r'^[ \w]{16}$' for this field
Bad format: content 'PayPal Europe S.' mismatches the expected format r'^[ \w]{16}$' for this field
Validation failed for reference '000963467753'
Bad format: content 'A82018474000' mismatches the expected format r'^\d{12}$' for this field
Bad format: content 'B57481517000' mismatches the expected format r'^\d{12}$' for this field
```

And the resulting OFX file does not import to Quicken.

Answer (score 0):

Try this puppy to get it to Excel, then it's easy to convert to OFX.

["Software : Conversores a Excel"](https://empresas.bankinter.com/www2/empresas/es/inicio/descarga/conversores_a_excel)

Comment: Sadly that's Windows only. Is there a Mac option?